# D&D Character stat roller (Java)

Tags: java, project, dice

So I am very new to the Java language and I'm attempting to put together a dice roller of sorts for character stat generation for D&D (Dungeons and Dragons).

What I want the program to do is roll x number of D6, x amount of times. X is to be input by the user. I also need the program to ask if it is to re-roll a result of 1 on a D6 roll. Plus, the program must only keep the highest 3 numbers of the rolled dice. It then needs to output the results of each grouping of dice rolls, instead of totaling them all together.

So an example would be: I want 4 D6 rolled 6 times, and re-roll 1's. 
The program output would be something along the lines of:

Your results are:

```
10
12
13
15
17
11.
```

I'm trying to write this with 3 classes, though I know it doesn't need to have 3 classes to operate. The additional classes are more of a requirement from a project standpoint.
I've managed to code what is necessary to roll a single dice, but as I said I'm very new and have almost zero idea on where to go with this.
The code I have so far is:

```
//Scanner is implemented in preparation for user input as more coding is 
//added
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RollDie {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int SIDES = 6;   // how many sides on the die?

    // roll should be 1 through SIDES
    int roll = (int) (Math.random() * SIDES) + 1;

    // print result
    System.out.println(roll);
}
}
```

Comment: Hint: use a for loop

Answer (score 0):

A one-class solution with freindly user input could look like this:

```
private final static int SIDES = 6;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Number of dice?");
    final int dice = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Number of rolls?");
    final int rolls = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Reroll result 1? Enter y for yes");
    final boolean reroll = scanner.next().equals("y");

    for (int r = 0; r < rolls; r++) {
        int allDice = 0;
        for (int d = 0; d < dice; d++) {
            int roll = (int) (Math.random() * SIDES) + 1;
            while (reroll && roll == 1) {
                roll = (int) (Math.random() * SIDES) + 1;
            }
            allDice += roll;
        }
        System.out.println(allDice);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot. However, it must only keep the highest 3 numbers of the dice rolled. For example, if rolling 4 D6 a single time, if the results are 4,3,5,2; the program must only keep the 5,4,3 for a total of 12.